# RSACryptoServiceProvider.EncryptValue returns NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I have a .NET 4.5 MVC application and I'm trying to user `RSACryptoServiceProvider` to encrypt some messages. However, when I try to use `EncryptValue()` I get a NotSupportedException. This is my code:

```
     RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = GetKeyFromContainer(_CONTAINER_NAME);

     byte[] byteEncrypted = RSA.EncryptValue(byteData); //Here is where I get the exception
```

And the GetKeyFromContainer method (copied from [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tswxhw92(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the private from the container and generates a new public key
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="ContainerName"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private RSACryptoServiceProvider GetKeyFromContainer(string ContainerName)
    {
        // Create the CspParameters object and set the key container 
        // name used to store the RSA key pair.
        CspParameters cp = new CspParameters();
        cp.KeyContainerName = ContainerName;

        // Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider that accesses
        // the key container
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cp);

        return rsa;
    }
```

Is this method not supported by .NET 4.5? Are there any alternative methods?

Comment: Is there some reason why you don't just use the `Encrypt` method?

Comment: Actually... No, there is not. I feel like a fool now. Thanks.

Comment: I ran into the same problem, and I need to use `.EncryptValue` because I rely on a wrapper around `RSA`, to which I pass an `RSACryptoServiceProvider`. The documentation indicates the method is not supported. Do you know if that is not supported under some context, or not supported at all?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk you should post your comment as an answer. This is a popular question now (1k views).